# Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, internet-explorer-9

I've upgraded from rich faces 3.3 to rich faces 4.2 because ajax didn't work for IE9. Now it still not works.

After receiving the Response IE gets an JS error *"SCRIPT58734: Der Vorgang konnte aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht fortgesetzt werden: c00ce56e."* while trying

```
data.responseText=request.responseText
```

on jsf.js.html?ln=javax.faces&conversationContext=2, Line 1 Row 21747

I think it's because of an incorrecct HTTP header

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF8
```

should be

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

Here The raw-response of the server

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF8
Content-Length: 293
Date: Tue, 17 Apr 2012 15:25:22 GMT

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="outtest"><![CDATA[<span id="outtest"><span     class="outhello">Hello !</span></span>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[2809980525147413088:295565165947012503]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

i'm usinng

```
javaee-web-api 6
myfaces-orchestra-core 1.4
Hibernate  4.1
Spring 3.1.1
Richfaces 4.2.0
Primefaces 3.2
jsf-api+impl 2.1.7
```

jstl 1.2

and running on tomcat 7

EDIT:
of now i'm sure its the header. I set a breakpoint in charles-proxy and edited the response header manually, with the edited http header IE9 showed the right result without any errors

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. The `charset` attribute in the `Content-Type` header is wrong and IE9 chokes on that with error `c00ce56e`.

JSF uses by default the one as obtained from [`ServletRequest#getCharacterEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getCharacterEncoding%28%29). This normally defaults to the client-specified one, or `null` if there's none (which is often the case). This is normally overrideable by some custom filter which calls [`request.setCharacterEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29).

Given the incorrect charset, this can only mean that your web application is somewhere calling [`request.setCharacterEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) with `"UTF8"` instead of `"UTF-8"`.

I'd start checking all filters and their configuration.

Comment: ok t hhought of a filter too. i think i'll add an response filter wich fixes the header as an termporary fix until i find the filter which causes this error. thanks

Comment: i second that.. i had exactly same problem when i had charset cp-1251 instead of windows-1251 - so keep an eye on your encoding!

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks! My fix was adding charset: `Response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";`

Comment: Apparently this will happen for any async loaded URL, if it has an invalid charset. In my case it was a couple of .html-templates for Angular and a fallback charset of "utf8" on the web server that triggered the error. I'll never forget the dash again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i got similar error but the problem was with the response headers content length. We had 24kb of data on the request header and we have to reduce it to half. That fixed the issue. i hope this helps someone.

Comment: I would recommend that this kind of answer goes to a comment instead an answer.