# SCRIPT58734: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer (9) keeps throwing this when I run an AJAX script trying to load content on to the page.

Comment: Hmm well I remember what the first 58,733 scripts do, but 58,734 is a new one.

Comment: @Jake does it associate the error with a line/file? Can you show us your code?

Comment: How about some code and some specific examples?...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194257/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-c00ce56e

Comment: Shows a serious lack of personal research.  This is exactly the sort of thing you pump into Google first.  A search on "c00ce56e" turns up all sorts of useful pages.

Comment: I did actually google something, thank you. I did as followed, and i'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a Content-Type that IE does not recognize. I would check the document you are trying to serve for the char-type and other than that I would check with the server admin if you do not have access to the server-side code.

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');` That's what I ahve.