# SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f78, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f78

Tags: javascript

Facing this issue only in IE.

Reproducible for first time in IE, from the second occurrence this issue is not reproduced.

The error we are able catch is “SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f78, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f78”.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati)

Comment: No, this is a different error code.

Comment: This is probably [ERROR_HTTP_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE(12152 / 
 0x2f78)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385465(v=vs.85).aspx).  Why the server is returning junk the first time is a complete mystery, since you don't show either your code or the server's code.  Questions needing debugging help really need a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f7d, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f7d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682160/internet-explorer-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2f7d-could-not-c)