# Getting error while fetching data using angularjs and REST api from sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

I'm fetching data from the `sharepoint` list using `angularjs` in regular intervals. After sometime, I'm getting error in the console as `SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.` I'm using `IE 10` as browser. Any idea about this error ?

Please find the method which i repeatedly calls to get data below.

```
// Method to get all the notifications for the user
    var getUserNotifications = function () {

        // Create a deferred object
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Url for getting the list with filters
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
                "_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + list + "')/items?" + filters;

        // API call to get the notification items from list 
        var method = $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });

        // Executing the method
        method.then(

            // Success function
            function (data) {

                var d = data.data.d.results;

                notification = d;


                // If timer is not started, then start it.
                if (!isTimerStarted) {

                    setInterval(function () {

                        getUserNotifications();

                    }, 3000);

                    isTimerStarted = true;
                }
        deferred.resolve(d);

            },
            // Error
            function (err) {
                deferred.reject("Error");
            }
        )
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati) might be related to your problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Try to set charset of the json to utf-8.

Comment: You mean like this... `"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8"` ?

Comment: With `,` between `verbose` and `charset`, not `;`

Comment: I have tried, but still the same error!

Comment: try without `odata=verbose`

Comment: It didn't fetched any results, so i have reverted the code back. I have noticed that the adfs has signed out, which has resulted in the error. So, I have increased the timeout of adfs server from 60 minutes  to 7 days. Now, it seems to be working fine.