# Internet Explorer sometimes aborted the request on the save method of Backbone model

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, backbone.js

When calling the save method, backbone is successfully rendered the server side script but fails to catch the callback of success method. This happens only using Internet Explorer.

The internet explorer throws error of

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2.

And the request has been aborted

How to fix this?

Comment: possible duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati