# I have in error with ie 10 : alk maps error with ie10

Tags: javascript

I use alk maps to show the path between two points and it works correctly in most browser, however in IE10 I have an error:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest. Network error 0x80070005, Access Denied
```

It works under IE9. I need your help, how can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati