# SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f76, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f76

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, session-variables

When my app`s session variable expires and if we try to perform any DB operation via AJAX call, I keep receiving this error only on IE (works fine on FF and chrome).

*SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f76, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f76*

Due to this my app is not redirecting. what can be the possible reasons?

TIA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this the redirection status code

> 303 See Other HTTP status code

is not recognize in IE, Changed to the status code to 308 and worked perfectly.

Comment: In my case, switching from 302 to 200 did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error from IE in case of adding incorrect header to ajax request.
It was such code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: someUrl,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        headers: "Cache-Control:no-cache"
    });
```

Problem was solved by changing code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: someUrl,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        headers: {
           'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
    });
```