# isomorphic-unfetch 302 response working slow in IE11

Tags: redirect, internet-explorer-11

I am using next.js and I need to send an AJAX request (I am using `isomorphic-unfetch`). Some cases the response is with 302 HTTP status code and I need to redirect to the URL that comes in response. For redirecting, I have tried with `Router.push(url)` and `window.location.href=url` due is a client redirection.

The problem is that in IE11 appears the error (other browsers works well)
[image]

The redirection is done but it takes about 10 seconds. I was googling and found this [SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati)  that describe a bit my problem but none of the proposed solutions fixed my problem. 
Other posts suggest changing the status response but I have no control to the requested endpoint so I can't change anything.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You can refer to [this thread](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB/issues/3587) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847078/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2f76-could-not-complete-the-operati), then, try to change the redirect code from 302 to 308.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT thanks for your response but I can't change the redirect code, I have no control over the backend