# AngularJS and Web API :- net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in chrome and error 00002efd in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

There are lots of question like my question but I didn't any working solution.

I am using AngularJS and WebApi2 in my application.

Here is the JS code which call the initial API.

```
(function (module) {
var baseUrl= "http://localhost:85";
module.constant('Config', baseUrl);
module.service('identities', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var uri = baseUrl+ '/api/controller/GetRole';

    var identities = {};
    identities.get = function () {
        var temp = $http.get(uri);
        console.log(temp, "identities");
        return temp;
    }
    return identities;
}]);
```

This function call the GetRole method in web API controller to retrieve user role.The output of this method is JSON with user details.

I have deployed the application on a server to port 85. When I run the application it's throwing error in Chrome:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

and in IE 11:

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

There is no log created in IIS for this request.

Using fiddler I got this in Raw with status code 502 in response.
The connection to 'localhost' failed.

> Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d).
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:85.

I have also tried by disabling the CORS in chrome but no luck.
IF I use IP address of server instead of localhost as baseUrl in angular JS code then it's working fine.
Why it's not working with localhost?

I am doing a GET call and Error for me is 00002efd not 00002ef3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati)

Comment: I already check that but no luck, for me its Get call not Post Call and error is  "Error 0x2efd".

Comment: You need to enable CORS in the web api. Install Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors. Add "config.EnableCors();" to the WebApiConfig.cs Register method

Comment: while installing package it gives: Install-Package :                          Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand                                                        When I run Get-Package -ListAvailable then there is no such package available. I am using vs2015.