# how can i find the complete error description thrown by Internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, networking, runtime-error, error-code

I am getting a network error in internet explorer on making a ajax call to the server.
Below is the error I get

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eef, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eef.
```

I want to find the exact **details** of the **network error** whose code is **exact** **0x2eef** or **00002eef**. I searched and went through a lot of documentation but couldn't find anywhere the detailed explanation of it. Can anyone help me out where and how can I find the exact details of the error code. Anywhere in Microsoft documentation or anywhere else ? Please help me.

Comment: you can click on the error number in the IE dev console to take you to the MSDN documentation....
or you can just copy and paste the full error into a browser address box and press enter and let your favorite search engine do the job.

Comment: Here's a stackoverflow answer found with bing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati

Comment: I have tried this, but not getting results for the exact code