# Random "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET", "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff"

Tags: php, ajax, apache, symfony

I have a Symfony 2.8 app.

All worked well with PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4, on Windows 10. Then I upgraded to PHP 7 (and kept Apache 2.4).

As soon as I upgraded I'm starting to get randomly the errors:

`"net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"` on Chrome

`"XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff."` on IE 11.

When I mean randomly I mean that I reload the same page, with the same content, and sometimes I have it, sometimes I don't. I do 5 or 6 Ajax calls on that page. It usually happens on those calls, but sometimes it does also on the main request.

I've not changed Apache configuration (apart from pointing to the right PHP version), and have made a diff of the php.ini, to make sure all parameters are the same.

I've already read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati) to no avail.

I tried `KeepAlive off` and also:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

and

```
KeepAliveTimeout 60
```

I've also tried: `SSLVerifyCLient optional_no_ca`

So, to wrap up: it's not a question of the content, nor it's browser dependant.

Also it does not appear to be something related to timing: the Ajax calls take 4-5 seconds to execute (but I saw them failing even when they take 1 second).

A peer of mine experiences the same issue (Apache 2.4, PHP 7 on Linux), but another does not (Apache 2.4, PHP 7 on Linux, but php runs as an Apache module).

Apache log is also clean.

Any clue?

Comment: same problem with symfony 3.3, did you solve it?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It does not happen in our prod env. So I live with that in dev :(

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your certificate. Test on http to confirm.

Comment: I solved it in a drastic way: a vagrant vm with linux