# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, jquery-file-upload, ie11-developer-tools

We have a piece of code which uploads multiple files to the server, interestingly this code is working fine on Chrome & Mozilla, but it's failing in Internet Explorer, receiving the following error

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2

We tried solutions mentioned in [SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati) but still getting a similar issue

We changed timeout value for Internet Explorer using the following
[this guide](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-keep-alive-time-out-internet-explorer) but it's no use.

We find out the line of code which causes a problem

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Private Helper for making servlet calls
        _servercall: function(urlStr, input, isAsync, dataT, ajaxcallback) {
            // Using the core $.ajax method
            $.ajax({
                // the URL for the request
                url : urlStr,
                async : isAsync,
                // the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
                data : input,
                // whether this is a POST or GET request
                type : "GET",
                // the type of data we expect back
                dataType : dataT,
                // code to run if the request succeeds;
                // the response is passed to the function
                success : function(json) {
                    console.log("Server call - Success");
                    ajaxcallback(json);
                },
                // code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
                // status codes are passed to the function
                // This needs to be better handled, more graceful error, ToDo
                error : function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log("Server call - error. Status " + status);
                    JCAAlert("com.ptc.windchill.enterprise.attachments.attachmentsResource.DO_APPLET_UPLOAD_ERROR");
                    this.cleanupUploadFields(this.wizardStep, null);
                },
                // code to run regardless of success or failure
                complete : function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log("The request is complete! Status " + status);
                }
            });
        },
```

This code is working fine till file number 12 on IE, but as soon as we select more than 12 files, it fails with above error?

Is this ajax limitation or something?

[image: See error snapshot]

Comment: Please try to check how much time your request needs to complete in IE and how much time out you had set in that registry key. Make sure that the timeout value is greater than the actual request time.

Comment: It requires fraction of second to complete the whole request in IE, it works when i keep fiddler on , I think fiddler is holding something, but not sure how should i proceed?

Comment: Can you please inform us, Which version of IE you are using currently? Also please inform us your OS build. Check the IE related updates and if you find any than try to install it and check again.

Comment: I have latest IE installed with no updates

Comment: I have latest IE installed with no updates plz check IE version and OS build https://imgur.com/a/hEH6nJ7 All other machines IE giving same error, if you search similar error on google but most of the users are facing similar issue, but no fesible solution or workaround, it seems request is getting stuck in IE or Apache but not getting clue where to start from

Comment: From IE side, I just got a solution to increase the timeout value. I did not get any other solution for this issue. You can also try to check for any solution from Apache side. If I will get any solution than I will try to inform you. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working now.

I followed the following article

https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/why-cant-i-open-more-than-6-proxy-sessions-in-internet-explorer-11/kb000012203

I Increased Maximum number of connections per server (HTTP 1.0) to 50

Then

Change the maximum number of connections per host (HTTP1.1) to 50

&

Set maximum number of webscoket connections per server to 50

it's working fine, I can upload files.

Thanks for your help.