# Disable HTTP2 in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, http2

I encountered problems in IE11 in combination with HTTP2 (SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.). These seem only to occur with IE11 / Win10 and HTTP2 enabled on our Tomcat.

After researching here and trying nearly every suggestion we came to the decision to disable HTTP2. Since we want to use HTTP2 for other browsers our solution is to disable it in IE 11.

On the first system it worked on the second system IE11 is just ignoring the setting and still transferring data with HTTP2.

We tried restarting IE and restarting the system but it still uses HTTP2.

Any ideas?

[image: Disable HTTP2 on IE11]

Comment: Try to reset the Internet Explorer and after that try to disable the HTTP2. Also try to check that your machine has latest Windows updates installed.

Comment: Didn't work, IE ist still ignoring my settings.

Comment: If possible for you than you can restore your machine from last backup and than try to change the setting to see if it helps to solve the issue or not.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Was there a solution discovered?  I have the same problem, IE is ignoring the unticking in _Internet Options_, even after a reboot.